# Mouse control panel starts on a custom tab instead of windows default tab. How to change back?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, control-panel

The installed drivers for the touchpad on my laptop have highjacked the default behavior for the mouse control panel window and starts it on its own custom tab. How do I revert that to the default behavior?

Some details for you:

Lenovo T450 ("Ultrabook"): http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t450/

Using standard issue drivers for touchpad: In Programs and Features, it's listed as "Synaptics Pointing Device Driver" and in the mouse control panel window, the tab that is showing by default is the "Think Pad" tab which just allows you to enable/disable touchpad and trackpoint.

Comment: Vague question, vague answer. Uninstall what you installed (just kidding). Seriously, if you add some details to this question we can try to give a helpful answer. What make/model of computer, what drivers you installed, etc. will be helpful.

Comment: Aye, fair and true. Just added a little info for you that is hopefully helpful.

Comment: That behavior is part of the customized Lenovo driver, about all you can do is install a generic synaptics driver...http://www.synaptics.com/resources

Comment: Well that kind of sucks. Pop that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!